# Symfony2 - FOSUserBundle - should I use FOS to rebuild user management?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

This is a practical question.

I have done registration and login without using FOS. I finished email verification and password reset functionalities also. I managed to make `HWIOAuthBundle` work and now I am able to sign up/login with social media.

I didn't use `FOS` because I have two registration form and login form in same page and that looked incredibly complicated to achieve with `FOS`.

Since then whenever I was searching any solutions to any problems reffering to User management I usually see beautifull `FOS` solutions. I started seeing that `FOS` works fine with multiple bundles including `SonataAdminBundle` and `HWIOAuthBundle`.

Should I rebuild my user system on `FOS` and is it possible to achieve what I mentioned before using it? (2 registration forms + 1 login form in same page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you have the time, to make your own solution work as you intend it to, then stick with it.
If not change to FOS.

Why not FOS in the first place? Simple: you have to overwrite/extend a shittone of stuff to make it work as you intend. In general, FOS User Bundle is a great bundle with a lot of functionality. But it has it's limitations and special things (like it requires every user to have a username and you have to either rewrite a huge part of it or use a quick and dirty solution like just overwriting the form and when the email is set set the username to the same).

I use FOS in several projects and it just works as advertised. If that's what you want, go for it.

Comment: I think the main reason not to use the FOSUserBundle is that it is essentially unmaintained.  You need to use the development version to run under S3.  The development version has been worked on for 4+ years without a stable release.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: @Cerad but stil, have you a better alternative? :P

Comment: Yep.  Write your own.  In most cases you only need a fraction of the functionality that FOSUserBundle provides.  The downside is that you do need to understand a bit about the security component including user providers and what not.  Tying your app to a dev-master branch is just not a good idea.  In fact, I have less than fond memories of doing so back in the 2.1 days and having things break when the master was updated.  At the very least, fork whatever branch you use.